# Multiple Email provider CNAME records for a single domain

Tags: email, domain, cname-record

Okay, I will say it in short.
I have a domain name from bigrock.

To configure Domain Email, **I used Zoho mail with admin@mydomain.com** which offers 5 GB Data. I updated appropriate CNAME records.

Later, I came to know that **With Domain, I get 5 emails** to use for free.

Disadvantage: Only 100 MB/email allowed. So I created a forward only account with **Sumit@mydomain.com** that forwards to **myid@gmail.com**.

Now when I test my forward only account it says no such user here and points to mail.zoho.com CNAME( where only admin@mydomain.com exists)

So essentially, can I have two Email providers configured with my domain?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MX record decides which server to connect to , to send an email to an address with a domain name.

there can be multiple MX records with different priorities. but you cannot specify an MX record for certain email addresses.

Comment: This. Almost. Depending on the mail server involved and how it is configured you could in fact forward mail for a specific user to a different SMTP server.  But the initial connection will begin with the highest priority (lowest number) MX record in your dns.